# how to divide two DATETIME into 15 mints slots in sql?

Tags: sql

I tried to create a stored procedure using SQL server. I have a start time and end time. I want to divide that into 15 minutes slots. Please help me to do that. Thank you.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetGCTeacherByDateRange]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Starttime DATETIME, 
    @Endtime DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SET @Starttime = '2018-03-12 10:00:00.000'
    SET @Endtime = '2018-03-12 11:15:00.000'
    
    -- do something
        
END
```

Sample output:

```
2018-03-12 10:00:00.000  2018-03-12 10:15:00.000
2018-03-12 10:15:00.000  2018-03-12 10:30:00.000
2018-03-12 10:30:00.000  2018-03-12 10:45:00.000
2018-03-12 10:45:00.000  2018-03-12 11:00:00.000
2018-03-12 11:00:00.000  2018-03-12 11:15:00.000
2018-03-12 11:15:00.000  2018-03-12 11:30:00.000
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. What RDBMS are you *really* using? What does the question have to do with the IDE MySQL Workbench? Please use tags correctly and don't use conflicting ones.

Comment: Also, if `@StartTime` and `@endtime` are parameters, why are you then setting their values within the stored procedure?

Comment: startTime and endTimes are input parameters.I'm using an SQL server. Sorry for incorrect tags

Comment: *"startTime and endTimes are input parameter"* So, to repeat myself, **"why are you then setting their values within the stored procedure"**? The parameters are pointless if you then `SET` their values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT @Starttime starttime, DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, @Starttime) endtime
              UNION ALL
              SELECT endtime, DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, endtime)
              FROM cte
              WHERE endtime < @Endtime )
SELECT * FROM cte 
/* OPTION (MAXRECURSION number) 
or, for indefinite needed depth
   OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) */
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=91dd85ec82b5be1ed8994e35143a4c59)

Comment: Nice. But default recursion limits this to just over a 25 hour period, after which you'll see `The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Increase allowed recursion depth, what a problem? use `OPTION (MAXRECURSION number);`. The number of needed depth may be easily calculated from divided range bounds.

Comment: A much bigger problem than the depth of recursion, is that a recursive CTE like this is just syntactic sugar for a while loop, and does not scale at all well. At the kind of scales this is likely to be at it probably isn't an issue, but there are better ways of doing this - [Generate a set or series without loops](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)

Comment: @GarethD That's true. But I doubt that OP needs in generate the timeslots for a period of several years regularly...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a numbers table, this is pretty straightforward:

```
SELECT  StartTime = DATEADD(MINUTE, 15 * Number, @Starttime),
        EndTime = DATEADD(MINUTE, 15 * (Number + 1), @Starttime)
FROM    Numbers
WHERE   Number >= 0
AND     Number <= CEILING(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @Starttime, @Endtime) / 15.0);
```

If you don't have a numbers table, this is still pretty straightforward, you just have to create your numbers on the fly:

```
DECLARE @Starttime DATETIME = '2018-03-12 10:00:00.000',
        @Endtime DATETIME = '2018-03-12 11:15:00.000';

WITH N1 AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (N)),
N2 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N1 AS N2),
N3 (N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS N1 CROSS JOIN N2 AS N2),
Numbers (Number) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N) - 1 FROM N3)

SELECT  StartTime = DATEADD(MINUTE, 15 * Number, @Starttime),
        EndTime = DATEADD(MINUTE, 15 * (Number + 1), @Starttime)
FROM    Numbers
WHERE   Number >= 0
AND     Number <= CEILING(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @Starttime, @Endtime) / 15.0);
```

More about this method, and other methods of creating sets on the fly can be found here:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)